# How to add ng-app after page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I've got a situation where I want to trigger an Angular-based widget *iff* a query arg is present in the current URL. My approach is to check (on page load) if the arg is present, and if so, append a bit of markup to the `<body>` that will get the app rolling:

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', []);

//init
$(function() {

  var widgetMarkup = "<div ng-app=\"exampleApp\"><div ng-include=\"'/partials/widget.html'\"></div></div>";

  if (window.location.href.indexOf('?arg') > -1) {
    $(document.body).append(widgetMarkup);
  }

});
```

**PROBLEM: The markup is added to the DOM, but has no effect.** But if I add the same markup to the raw HTML file, the app is picked up and the partial is rendered. Do I need to tell Angular to re-scan the page for directives?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you want is [`angular.bootstrap`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).  Call it when your DOM is ready and everything has been appended.

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['exampleApp']);
```

This will start angular on the document, as if it had `ng-app` on it.  You can bootstrap it to whatever element you want though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually bootstrap your app.

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', []);
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('?arg') > -1) {
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['exampleApp']);
    });
  }
```

More info here: [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)