# how initialize angularjs ng-app after page loaded

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

A load content from jquery ajax, that contain ng-app="" and other directive.
But it does't initialize.
Now, How initialize a angularJS initialize ng-app that was added after page loaded.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" class="uk-width-3-5 uk-grid">
                    <input class="uk-width-4-5" ng-model="classe" placeholder="Nivel academico..." type="range" min="1" max="13" value="14" name="classe" required>
                    <b class="uk-width-1-5">{{classe}}ª Classe</b>
                </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add ng-app after page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456183/how-to-add-ng-app-after-page-load)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use angular.bootstrap. Call it when your DOM is ready and everything has been appended.

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

This will start angular on the document, as if it had ng-app on it. You can bootstrap it to whatever element you want though.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    Hello {{greetMe}}!
  </div>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js"></script>

  <script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.greetMe = 'World';
  }]);

angular.element(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample example on how to bootstrap an application